# Updating images cause memory leak in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, debugging, dom, memory-leaks

I just can't find out why this code produce a memory leak in IE8:

```
ws.onmessage = function (e) {
var img = document.getElementById("image");
img.src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,'+e.data; //base64 encoded image
img = null;
e.data = null;
e = null;
}
```

i think it leaks, because of the Dom acess from Javascript.

Comment: It would be beneficial if you're able to provide a link or Fiddle that we can see where the symptoms you're dealing with can be seen.  We can't help you out a whole lot from that piece of code alone!

Comment: I don't know what you suspect is leaking, but keep in mind that  your handler function is closing over the outer environment, which includes `ws`, so in effect, you've got a circular reference to `ws` via the closure. This sort of closure leak is a known issue in older IE.

Comment: ...not even sure how this code could work in IE8, since their handler properties don't pass an event object as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

The image is attached to the DOM when the `src` property is changed, so the binding to each data URI is retained until the user leaves the page. Do one of the following:

- Remove the image from the DOM first
- Store a dummy image in a `documentFragment`, update it, then append it to the DOM